# Multiple scope uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wanted to clarify the behavior of multi-scope uniqueness validation. The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) says:

> Or even multiple scope parameters. For example, making sure that a
>   teacher can only be on the schedule once per semester for a particular
>   class.

```
class TeacherSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, :scope => [:semester_id, :class_id]
end
```

My understanding of this is that I could have a teacher teaching two classes in the same semester but not the same class, and I could have a teacher teaching the same class in different semesters.  Is this correct? All 3 fields must match some existing record in order for validation to fail?

Is there a way to validate it so that it fails if either semester_id or class_id matches?

Comment: Why not add two validations, each with a different scope?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My understanding of this is that I could have a teacher teaching two classes in the same semester but not the same class, and I could have a teacher teaching the same class in different semesters. Is this correct? All 3 fields must match some existing record in order for validation to fail?

Yes, this is correct. Thing about it as "for every unique value of `scope`, the field can only show up once." When `scope` is an array, a "unique value for scope" is a combination of the fields' values.

> Is there a way to validate it so that it fails if either semester_id or class_id matches?

So a teacher should never teach twice in a semester, and also should never ever teach the same class, even in a different semester? That doesn't seem right, but you could do that with a validation on each:

```
class TeacherSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, :scope => :semester_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, :scope => :class_id
end
```

Comment: No, it does not make sense in the context of the documentation's example. Just wondering how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just came to understand how uniqueness validation works with scope and I'd like to share it with you all.

Let's say if you have a multiple departments in an organisation and any employee can belong to two or more departments as well at the same time. To make sure that an employee's email id is unique in each department, we use scope.

By doing it this way, we can ensure that no two employees with same email address works in the same department. Also we can find out all the departments in which a particular employee works.

In simpler terms, uniqueness validation with scope works on couple of both the attributes (email, department in our case).